# How to keep a lifetime TCP socket listener running on Blazor application?

Tags: asp.net-core, sockets, tcp, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have been running Blazor application for multiple years now and I suffer from my TCP Socket listener always getting disconnected randomly.

I have tried both direct IIS hosting and plesk running on Windows (IIS)
My goal is to keep the TCP Socket listener running forever without being interrupted. I believe that the socket gets closed due to the website going idle sometimes.

Regards and thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not have this tcp socket listener running separate for example under a windows service?

Comment: @DenisMicheal Basically there are modules that directly connect to the website where my users are able to execute actions that's sent directly to those modules to perform those actions, so even if I ran the tcp socket listener separately, I still have to connect it to the website somehow.

Comment: Does reload help?https://alldev.co.uk/reload-blazor-server-on-connection-down-in-net-6/.

Comment: @QiangFu I believe that's related to the browser<->server connection which is irrelevant, My socket listener is totally coded in the backend and started from Main method. I believe the socket dies as soon as the website go Idle and there is no way of re-establishing the listener.

Comment: You can’t. Disconnection is a fact of life in networking. The idea is to make your code robust against it, not to assume that you can make it never happen.

Comment: I've seen a timer used to address this sort of issue. Handler just checks on state of socket and reinitialize if necessary.

Comment: @JoelR.Hall Indeed, but that's a means of detecting the disconnects, not of preventing them, which is what the OP is asking for here.

Comment: Networks aren't designed and built for "Permanent" connections.  Code your application to handle that fact of life.

Comment: @user207421, that is a means of both detecting and correcting disconnects. As you yourself pointed out above, "Disconnection is a fact of life in networking", so the best that can be done is to anticipate and correct.

Comment: @Joel Indeed, again, but not a means of ***preventing*** them, which is what the OP is asking for here, and what I said above. Do read the question, and address what I actually said, not what you think it says. You are actually in a state of furious agreement with me.

Answer (score -2):

you should make a multitask application which can control sockets in separate tasks and each socket must be in a single task so by entering a socket data by event management you can control all the sockets in your application.

by System.Net.Sockets(in C#) the Sockets from your website requests must be processed and a multitask application by System.Threading.Task can help you to do it.

your listener application in your server can be a windows service or a console application or even Windows form application(I used this and it works very good with sockets in my website)

controlling tasks needs precise checking of socket states to avoid lock or malfunctioning.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

Try using SignalR with the BLazor app to establish a SignalR connection.
Also make sure your hosting environment doesn't interfere with long-lived connections.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).